# Why a DFT of 2 senes is very noisy even with frequence sampling 5 times bigger?

Tags: fourier-series

I've set up this case to try to understand DFT implementing a real case in Excel

Frame Size $\;\color{blue}{(T}$)**:**  5 s
Time Sampling $\;\color{blue}{(TS}$)**:** 0,1 s
Block Size $\;\color{blue}{(N = TT/TS+1)}$**:** 51
Sampling Rate  $\;\color{blue}{(FS = TT/TS+1)}$**:** 10 Hz
Frequency Resolution $\;\color{blue}{(FR = FS/(N-1))}$**:** 0.2 Hz

In `time spectrum` I have put just 2 sines functions added

The firt sine  has amplitude $\color{blue}{10}$, phase $ \color{blue}{\pi/3}$ and frequency  $\color{blue}{2}$ Hz.
The second sine  has amplitude $\color{blue}{5}$, phase $\color{blue}{0}$ and frequency $\color{blue}{1}$ Hz:      $ \color{blue}{\quad ( n = 0\; to \;50)}$

$$ \color{blue}{X[n] = 10\, \sin{(2\pi t 2 + \pi/3)}+ 5\, \sin{(2\pi t 1)}}$$

So I have generated DFT values where $\color{blue}{\; k=0\; to\; 50\quad }$   and $\color{blue}{\quad x_k=a_k + ib_k}\;$**:**

$$\color{blue}{a_k = (1/N) \; \Sigma_{n=0,N-1} X_n \cos{(2 \pi n k /N)}} $$
$$\color{blue}{b_k = (1/N) \; \Sigma_{n=0,N-1} X_n \sin{(2 \pi n k /N)}} $$

After, I've calculated module $\color{blue}{A}$ and phase $\color{blue}{\Phi}$ for $ \color{blue}{\; ( n = 0\; to \;50)}$

$$\color{blue}{A_k =  \sqrt{(a_k)^2  + (b_k)^2}} $$
$$\color{blue}{\Phi_k = atan2(b_k, a_k)} $$

I consider in my analysis 
$$\color{blue}{ Freq_k = k.FS/(N-1)} $$

Now my doubt arise. In my understanding, the signal should be concentrated in the values of frequencies $\color{blue}{1}$ Hz  and $\color{blue}{2}$ Hz. It is not. Not even remotely. Amplitude $\color{blue}{A_k}$ for $\color{blue}{8.2}$ and $\color{blue}{9.2}$ Hz are very strong. In short, the frequency spectrum is very noise. Also $\color{blue}{2.2}$  Hz and $\color{blue}{8}$ hz amplitudes are almost half of $\color{blue}{1}$ Hz amplitude.

I'm working with frequence sampling $\color{blue}{10}$ Hz,  five times than maximum detected frequency ($\color{blue}{2}$ Hz).

What's happening?

To check if I had made a mistake, I calculated the DTF inverse and the original signal was restored exactly!

Comment: It is not clear that there is a problem. You will always get extra peaks at the high end of the spectrum, in particular $A_{N-k} = A_k$, due to aliasing. You can interpret those peaks as existing at $A_{-k}$ instead. Also, since the period of your signal is exactly 50 samples, you should drop the 51st one, and then the spectrum ought to be what you expect.

Comment: Not exactly, my total period is 5 s, 51 samples, 0.1 s between samples. When I take out the last data, the inverse DFT not match anymore. I've made a complete IDFT and all real part match with original sign and all complex part is 0.

Comment: I'm studying the aliasing. I'm new in DFT so it's hard for me.

Comment: Now I'm using k from -25 to 25, 51 samples. It improves a lot!  The bigger values are -2Hz, -1Hz, 1Hz and 2Hz, but 2,2 Hz amplitude is around 25% of 2  Hz amplitude. Is it normal?

Answer (score 1):

DFT frequencies may be easier to think of as going from -SR/2 to SR/2 instead of from 0 to SR.  Then for real-valued input, F(-k) = conj(F(k)).

Comment: I'm new in DFT. I will try this approach.

Comment: I've made the changes and now I'm using k from -25 to 25 (51 samples from - 5 Hz to 5 Hz).  It improves a lot! The bigger values are -2Hz, -1Hz, 1Hz and 2Hz, but 2,2 Hz amplitude is around 25% of 2  Hz amplitude, my sampling rate is 10 Hz. Is it normal?

Comment: you should use BlockSize = TotalTime / SampleTime without any +1, you may be getting bin leakage because the waveform is a sine wave with one extra sample; for a sine wave the last sample of the input will be different from the first sample (this is normal)